# How do I create plots from dynamic input?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to shiny programming. I am currently working on a app where users can upload data and then select which variables should be plotted. Here, I ran into the problem that only empty plots were returned by ggplot. This is not only true for my specific dataset, but I get the same error when I use the `iris` dataset.

Here is my App.R document:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Plot Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput(inputId = "x_input",
                      choices = "",
                      label = "Choose x-Axis",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      selectize = TRUE),
          selectInput(inputId = "y_input",
                      choices = "",
                      label = "Choose y-Axis",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      selectize = TRUE)
        ),
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel("Sample of Input Data",
           
           tableOutput("table"),
           "Plot of Input Data",
           plotOutput("plot")

        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table = renderTable({
    #req(combined_df)
    return(head(iris))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "y_input",
      choices=names(iris))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "x_input",
      choices=names(iris))
  })
  
  output$plot = renderPlot({
    iris %>% 
      plot()
   # plot = iris %>% 
   #         ggplot(aes(x = input$x_input, y = input$y_input))
   # print(plot)

    })   

  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Regarding how i formulate the `output$plot` command i get different errors/ problemes.

1. Using `base` R with `plot()`:

   ```
   output$plot = renderPlot({
       iris %>% 
         plot(x = input$x_input, y = input$y_input)

       })
   ```

which throws the following error:

```
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
  173: plot.window
  172: localWindow
  171: plot.default
  170: plot
  169: %>%
  168: renderPlot [dirrectory....]
  166: func
  126: drawPlot
  112: <reactive:plotObj>
   96: drawReactive
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$plot
    1: shiny::runApp
```

2. If I don't specify the x and y values using `base` R, I do get a plot output:

```
output$plot = renderPlot({
    iris %>% 
      plot()
})
```

See [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEN6L.png). This is also unsatisfactory as i only want a single xy plot.

3. Using `ggplot()` :

```
output$plot = renderPlot({
  plot = iris %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x = input$x_input, y = input$y_input))
})
```

I get a empty plot without any datapoints. This stays the same regradless if I wrap the `ggplot()` function in a `print()` or `show()` statement or none at all.

4. The last combination is a variation of number three, also using `ggplot()` :

```
output$plot = renderPlot({
  plot = iris %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x = input$x_input, y = input$y_input))+
           geom_point()
})
```

This returns an otherwise empty graph with a dot in the middle (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN3u3.png)).

Important to note: these errors stay the same regardless if the `tidyverse` package/ notation is used.

At this point I am running out of ideas how to tackle this seemingly simple problem, so any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For your fourth approach the issue is that `input$x_input` and ... are character strings. To tell ggplot2 that these character strings are columns in your data you have to use e.g. the .`data` pronoun, i.e. use `.data[[input$x_input]]`. See e.g. [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-ggplot2) and e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75593889/problem-with-reactive-geom-boxplot-in-shiny/75594149#75594149.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Shiny; your plotting code is simply wrong, and it isn't clear why you are using a pipe here at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. We need to wrap the `input$` in `.data[[]]` (alternatively in `!! sym()`).
2. Calling `ggplot` alone isn't enough, we also need `geom_point()`

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Plot Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "x_input",
                  choices = "",
                  label = "Choose x-Axis",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  selectize = TRUE),
      selectInput(inputId = "y_input",
                  choices = "",
                  label = "Choose y-Axis",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  selectize = TRUE)
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel("Sample of Input Data",
              
              tableOutput("table"),
              "Plot of Input Data",
              plotOutput("plot")
              
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table = renderTable({
    #req(combined_df)
    return(head(iris))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "y_input",
      choices=names(iris))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "x_input",
      choices=names(iris))
  })
  
  output$plot = renderPlot({
    iris %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = .data[[input$x_input]],
                 y = .data[[input$y_input]])) + 
      geom_point()
    
    
  })   
  
  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```